# VBA Unique word sort

Tags: vba, excel, google-forms

Trying to find unique names in column B, and copy any rows with said name to new worksheet.

i.e. Alex clocks in twice this week he will fill two rows with data, I want to move his two rows of data to their own worksheet. Fred only clocks in once and creates 1 row of data, I want to move his row to a new worksheet.

Problem, it is copying row 2 to multiple of the new worksheets

link to my file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JZla8ySwEotn91m8trh2_2fNLBNak-of98HQJ0YCP_0/edit?usp=sharing

code i'm using so far:

```
Sub Copy_To_Worksheets()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
Dim My_Range As Range
Dim FieldNum As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim CCount As Long
Dim WSNew As Worksheet
Dim ErrNum As Long

'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
Set My_Range = Range("A2:E" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
My_Range.Parent.Select

If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
   My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
           vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
    Exit Sub
End If

'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
FieldNum = 2

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'Add a worksheet to copy the a unique list and add the CriteriaRange
Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add

With ws2
    'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
    My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

    'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
    Lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("A1:A" & Lrow)

        'Filter the range
        My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
         Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

        'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
        CCount = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                 .Areas(1).Cells.Count
        On Error GoTo 0
        If CCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                 & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                 & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                   vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
        Else
            'Add a new worksheet
            Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            On Error Resume Next
            WSNew.Name = cell.Value
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                ErrNum = ErrNum + 1
                WSNew.Name = "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000")
                Err.Clear
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            'Copy the visible data to the new worksheet
            My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            With WSNew.Range("A1")
                ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                .Select
            End With
        End If

        'Show all data in the range
        My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

    Next cell

    'Delete the ws2 sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

End With

'Turn off AutoFilter
My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

If ErrNum > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
         & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
         & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
End If

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
My_Range.Parent.Select
ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: This post seems to be a duplicate of you prior post [VBA Search for unique value in column, move all rows containing found value to new sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578305/vba-search-for-unique-value-in-column-move-all-rows-containing-found-value-to-n). Please refrain from posting the same question multiple times or explain how this post deviates from the prior post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would likely do it this way, but this would need more error checking.

```
Option Explicit


Sub MovePeeps()

Dim emp As New Collection
Dim ws, tmpWs, tw As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim empExist As Boolean
Dim i, j, k, m As Integer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
empExist = False

'get unique employee names into the emp collection
'cycle through the used range - i= column of names
For i = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'cycle through all peopel in the emp collection
    For j = 1 To emp.Count
        'check if person in cell = person in emp collection
        If ws.Cells(i, 2) = emp(j) Then
            empExist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    'if person is in emp collection already reset empExist and exit loop without adding again
    If empExist = True Then
        empExist = False
        Exit For
    End If
    'otherwise add that person to the collection
    emp.Add ws.Cells(i, 2)
Next i
'create a worksheet named after each item in the emp collection
For i = 1 To emp.Count
    wb.Worksheets.Add After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
    Set tmpWs = wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
    tmpWs.Name = emp(i)
    'add header row to each sheet
    ws.Cells(1, 2).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=tmpWs.Cells(1, 1)
Next i
'copy all data to the new sheets
m = 1
For j = 1 To emp.Count
    For Each tw In wb.Worksheets
        'if the worksheet (tw) is the same name as the person in emp(j) then set the tmpWS variable
        If tw.Name = emp(j) Then
            Set tmpWs = tw
            Exit For
        End If
    Next tw
    For i = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If ws.Cells(i, 2) = emp(j) Then
            'find blank row on the sheet we are copying to
            Do While tmpWs.Cells(m, 2) <> ""
                m = m + 1
            Loop
            'copy the row to the tmpWS
            ws.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=tmpWs.Cells(m, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    'reset our blank row counter.
    m = 1
Next j

End Sub
```